# DIV content fade in/out confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fade

I have searched through StackOverflow posts and various forums, but cannot find an answer. I have found answers for similar questions, but nothing breaks it down quite enough for me to understand. I understand a good deal of PHP and HTML, but am having difficulty with scripts.

How can I click on a link, get the href (or what do I need?), have it fade out the current content, find the content I'm trying to load (href or whatever in the link) and load it, *then* fade it in?

My previous problems with random bits of code I've tried:

1. While going from page to page if another link was clicked while loading, it would only partially fade the second page in.
2. Each link had to have it's own script to direct it there. Could never figure out how to make it get the href of the link clicked.
3. Examples were so complicated I couldn't modify them to what I needed exactly. I need to understand the process of it.

Comment: I'd drop the PHP tag.  This question has little to nothing relating to PHP.

Comment: Can you show some code or setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please explain problem #1 better

Comment: GigaWatt: Good point, sorry.

JayBlanchard: A couple answers below are similar to what I have.

@Roy: If you clicked on a link to another page, it would start to fade out the page, but while any kind of fading happens and you click another link, it would mess up the DIV fade, and the result would be barely visible or partially faded out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){
   $('.content').fadeOut().load('/path/to/script', function() {
      $(this).fadeIn();
   });
});
```

The key to this to use a HTML page or PHP script which can return the content you want. You might want to retrieve the URL from another element or hard-code it into your script - your call. For more information about how `load()` works, [visit jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Okay so... explain the '/path/to/script' please. You mean the script to which I retrieve the URL?

Comment: Yeah, the path where you're getting your content from. It could be a PHP script echoing out content, or even a static HTML page with text

Comment: Alright, but what about my issue with overlapping fade values? If I click any other link while one is fading, it will mess everything up :c I don't know how to explain.

Comment: The element will fade back in as soon as the content has loaded. If you select another link, the element will fade out and load new content. This is fine as long as you only have one link with the class of 'link'

Comment: This is the same frustration I've gone through before... 

1) Where do I put this script? 

2) Do I call this script in 'onclick' in an href? 

I created it with `function fadeContent()`, so do I add this into the links?

`<a href="map.php" onclick="fadeContent();">Map</a>`

Comment: 1) In a <script> tag before the </body> tag ends. Make sure you include jQuery. 2.) You do not need any more functions or onclick. Just make sure your link has a classname of 'link' - e.g. `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">Link</a>`

Comment: Okay I did it as you said, but the script isn't doing anything. I checked it with Firebug, and it doesn't show any activity. I think the problem is the link location... If my href is `javascript:void(0)`, then how is it showing the script what page to load?

Comment: Okay here is the link to my [testing page](http://vanwa-arda.com/fadetest.php). The Index button is what I'm using your code for, the Join button is previous code I have that works, but I have the same issue with fade overlapping.

Comment: EDIT: Apparently GoDaddy likes to hide page source... Here is a [link](http://vanwa-arda-server.dyndns.org/fadetest.php) to my DNS.

Comment: I'm not writing your code for you. I've pointed out exactly what you need to do. You need to research jQuery and how it operates - at the moment you don't know how it can capture events and manipulate elements. My answer is meaningless until you do some basic research

Comment: I wasn't asking for code to be written, I was asking for an explanation on what is going wrong with fade overlap. But alright. More research it is, instead of a knowledgeable person's help... xD

Answer (score 0):

I actually developed something just like this some time ago.

The trick (or a trick) is to wrap your page an an `iframe`, and on the parent window, have a div element that fades into view when a page is requested, and fades out when the page loads.

The parent window looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&lt; Page1 &gt;</title>
        <style>
            html, body{
                font-family:helvetica;
            }
            #fade, iframe {
                position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                border-width:0px;
                z-index:-1;

                opacity:0;

                color:#AAA;
                background-color:#FFF;

                -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
                -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
                -o-transition: opacity 300ms;


            }
            iframe {

                opacity:1;

                z-index:1;
                background-color:#FFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fade">
        <h1>Loadin..</h1>
        </div>
        <iframe src="p1.html"></iframe>

        <script>

            var fade    = document.getElementById("fade");
            var iframe  = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];


            var t = null;

            addEventListener("message", function(e) {

                if(t!=null)clearTimeout(t);

                fade.style.zIndex = "2";

                t=setTimeout(function(){
                    fade.style.opacity = "1";
                },0);

            }, true);


            iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {

                if(t!=null)clearTimeout(t);

                t=setTimeout(function(){
                    fade.style.opacity = "0";
                },0);

                document.title = iframe.contentWindow.document.title;


                t=setTimeout(function(){
                    fade.style.zIndex = "-1";
                },300);

            }, true);


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the subpages would each have the following code:

```
<script>
function go() {
    window.parent.postMessage("showLoadScreen", "*");
}
</script>
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="go()">somepage.html</a>
```

This code is a little different in that the fader doesn't pop up unless the requested resource is taking awhile to load. But, you get the idea.

Since the `iframe` only exists for visual purposes, it *shouldn't* cause any major problems. However, note that this code uses HTML5's `postMessage` API, and you may want to tweak it a bit.

Comment: This is a solid chunk of code, but nothing was explained in it :/ I don't like to use code unless it's clear to me. I think I might go to the method that Jamie posted...